# Get the current LatLng dynamically (Google Map)

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have the following code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
    <title>Geolocation Service</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var lat = ???;
            var lng = ???;
            var map = {
                center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                zoom:5,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), map);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapcontainer">
        <!--Map goes here-->
    </div>
</body>
<style>
   *
    {
        margin: 0;
    }

    #mapcontainer
    {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

In my variable `lat` and `lng`, I set them to `???` because I dont know how to get the my current position. I just started learning Google Geolocation API. Thanks!

Comment: And why it is tagged in php?

Comment: Similar questions already have been answered on Stackoverflow. Please check these: [Question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748204/get-current-position-in-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-and-get-the-dot-to-follow) [Question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940767/how-to-get-client-location-using-google-maps-api-v3) Also you should check the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) where everything is described in details.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: The ???s you have are where you *define* the lat and lng, not where you query a value. To set a google map for a particular place, it's easiest to go to gmaps, type in the place you're looking for and copy the lat/lng values from the url. To query an existing map for lat/lng coords... well, read the API docs :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Client location using Google Maps API v3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940767/how-to-get-client-location-using-google-maps-api-v3)

Answer (score 1):

If you load Google Maps with [Google Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/), you can use the `google.loader.CurrentLocation` to get a location based on IP as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4919754/1375553)

Another option would be to utilize  [HTML5 GeoLocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html):

```
function initialize() {

   // Is HTML5 geolocation supported
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

         var lat = position.coords.latitude;
         var lng = position.coords.longitude;
         //..

      });
   } 

}
```

You might find [Google Maps JavaScript API - Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation?csw=1) example helpful.